# WebApi for Email delivery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a Web API controller inside my ASP.NET MVC 4 Website to specifically send emails so that I can consume it for this purpose and eventually provide it to other consumers (Mobile, etc).

Everything is working fine but I want to use it asynchronously, altough it's not working that way, my website blocks until the work is finished.

I have a regular Controller where I call a helper class that calls the API.

Controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
{
    ExternalApiCalls extApi = new ExternalApiCalls();
    await extApi.PostContactUs(model).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return RedirectToAction("ContactUsSuccess", "Account");
}
```

Helper Class Code :

```
public class ExternalApiCalls
{
    public HttpClient client { get; set; }
    public ExternalApiCalls()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10239/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task PostContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/WAPIMail",    model).ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Web API Controller :

```
public class WAPIMailController : ApiController
{
    public void PostContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {              
        // Send Email Here
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Shouldn't you be awaiting the result of `PostContactUs`? Also, `Thread.Sleep` works in an entirely different way than the Async API. Calling Thread.Sleep simply pauses the current thread, so it's not asynchronous.

Comment: I edited my code, since just like you said I should be awaiting the result of PostContactUs. So removing the Thread.Sleep my application will not block waiting for the Api work ? Thanks

Comment: I remove the Thread.Sleep and I tested it however it is blocking my website. Somehow this is not running asynchrony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed how to do it..

For brevity's sake, I am showing oversimplified code, see below:

**Controller :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        new ExternalApiCalls().MailContactUs(model); 
        return RedirectToAction("ContactUsSuccess", "Account");
    }
```

**Helper Class :**

```
    public void MailContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/WAPIMail/MailContactUs", model).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**Web API Controller :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void MailContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        //Email Logic Here
    }
```